# Merge Outlook .pst file with Outlook.com and Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have been using Outlook for years to manage all of my emails. Recently, we have upgraded and have started to use Office 365 to manage our mail domains which are accessed through outlook.office365.com.

What I would like to do is merge my Outlook file one my desktop PC with my Outlook Office 365 account. I would like for all of my same folders to appear and all of my saved emails to be syncronised. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just a check - you want the emails to be SYNCHRONISED between the 2 accounts? Not just to do a one-off move from the old to the new?